# How to overcome bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to install the realtek alc665 driver using the package [realtek-linux-audiopack-4.06a](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-ac-97-audio-codecs-software) for Linux on my laptop running Debian 10. (You can also view it directly through [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x9Cu8wTaxWjGXMiSflU6q1iAl2iyEM3P))

In order to install it, I've been following the instructions included in `realtek-linux-audiopack-4.06a/Readme.txt` file which says to run `./config` in the directory where `alsa-driver-1.0.14-4.06a` is extracted. When I run `./configure` the output from bash is: (Check out the last two lines)

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for current directory... /home/dsaki/Downloads/realtek-linux-audiopack-4.06a/alsa-         driver-1.0.14-4.06a
checking cross compile... 
checking for directory with kernel source... /lib/modules/4.19.0-8-amd64/source
checking for directory with kernel build... /lib/modules/4.19.0-8-amd64/build
checking for kernel linux/version.h... yes
checking for kernel linux/autoconf.h... yes
checking for kernel version... 0.0.0
checking for GCC version... ./configure: eval: line 4836: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./configure: eval: line 4836: `my_compiler_version=8.3.0-6)'
```

Here is the file `configure` in which the error has occurred. I've written down the whole part that I guess is responsible for the error: (Line 4836 is shown by a comment)

```bash
      typevar=my_compiler_type
      versionvar=my_compiler_version
      ac_compiler_type=""
      ac_compiler_version=""
      for i in $my_compiler; do
        case $i in
        gcc-[0-9]*|*-gcc-[0-9]*)
         if test -z "$ac_compiler_type"; then
           ac_compiler_type=gcc
         fi
         if test -z "$ac_compiler_version"; then
           ac_compiler_version=`echo $i | sed -e 's/^.*gcc-\([0-9.]\+\).*$/\1/'`
         fi
         ;;
        *gcc*|*GCC*)
          if test -z "$ac_compiler_type"; then
           ac_compiler_type=gcc
          fi
          ;;
        egcs-*)                            #    LINE 4836 STARTS HERE
         ac_compiler_type=egcs
         if test -z "$ac_compiler_version"; then
           ac_compiler_version=`echo $i | sed -e 's/egcs-\(.\+\)$/\1/'`
         fi
         ;;
        *cc*)
         if test -z "$ac_compiler_type"; then
           ac_compiler_type=cc
         fi
         ;;
       [0-9].[0-9]*)
         if test -z "$ac_compiler_version"; then
           ac_compiler_version="$i"
         fi
         ;;
       esac
    done
    eval $typevar="$ac_compiler_type"
    eval $versionvar="$ac_compiler_version"
```

I need to fix this to be able to proceed the installation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a link to what you are trying to install. Where did you find this script? It doesn't look like the error is from the line you show, so we'll need to see the whole thing.

Comment: Also, try editing and adding some debug messages. Your `$ac_compiler_version` variable, which is being set in the section you show, seems to be getting an extra parenthesis. If you add an `echo` statement to each of the cases there, you should be able to see which one is being run and setting your variable so we can focus on that one. Even better, of course, would be to report this bug to wherever you found this script.

Comment: You need to find a line containing `my_compiler_version=` that's around 4836 lines after an `eval` statement.

Comment: @roaima, worse, it could be `eval "$somevar"`, with a multi-line variable

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the comments. I edited my question and now there is a link to the package.

Comment: I'm new to Linux and I don't know bash scripting so much yet. Anyway, Thanks for your response.

Comment: @roaima I'm pretty sure it's the next to last line shown in the question: `eval $typevar="$ac_compiler_type"`. If `$ac_compiler_type` evaluates to something with a trailing `)`, that would explain the error. But we'd need to know the values of `$my_compiler` to debug further.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Peter!

Comment: Are you sure you want to build that source? Some vendors have some musty "Linux drivers" on their pages, that probably worked 10 or 15 years ago at the time of the 2.2.x kernels, while the hw is supported in the mainline kernel and may only need some firmware files to work. Anyways, rather than debugging configure scripts from 15 years ago, which is a fool's errand, try regenerating them with `autoreconf -i` (some sources have an `autogen.sh` script that does all that for you).

Comment: In this case, that configure script probably makes assumptions about the format of the output of `gcc --version` of some ancient gcc, and even if you manage to overcome that, it would be pointless.

Comment: @– mosvy Thanks for your comments. I didn't find ```autogen.h```.